# How to enable registrationless auth (magic-links) with keycloak

Tags: authentication, authorization, keycloak, one-time-password

we are trying to build an application which is accessable via onetime passwords without a "user" having the need to register.

We did came accross the term `magic-links` sent via email, but there is only some old experimental keycloack extention for this.

Is there any way to build some auth flow like the following with keycloack?

User A is a fully registered User creating some document. This document needs some interaction with a Third Party Person (TPP) not registered.
Now User A sends an E-Mail invite to the TPP with a link to the document. When the TPP opens the link our application should ask for the email address and send a magic link or code to this email. Whith that email or magic code the user gets access to the document for the time it takes to complete the approval process. After the work of the TTP is done, the access should expire (or expire automatically after X days not used).

It does sound quite similar to what is possible with SaaS offerings like https://magic.link/ or https://www.arengu.com/ but we are using keycloack and would like to integrate it into it as well.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this with keycloak?

Comment: This Github repo (https://github.com/richardjkendall/login-with-email) showcases how to implement a magic link feature with Keycloak. 

However, for me, the problem is that it does not work if the user does not use the same browser to Open the mail link (sessions cookie of Keycloak not shared between browsers).

Seems like all magic link solutions have this limitation.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is outdated, but perhaps someone else coming along may find this useful.  There is a newer implementation of this feature provided here: https://github.com/p2-inc/keycloak-magic-link

We have found it usable and useful for our needs and works well in the latest version of Keycloak (18.x).

Comment: Thank you we are still looking for a good solution  we'll have a look.